# Smartcard (CAC) authentication using HttpClient

Tags: java, keystore, smartcard, cac

Every day I need to connect to a website that requires authentication using a CAC. I connect this website and then check if there are any notifications for me.

I would like to automate this routine. I'm planning to use an `HttpClient`, but I'm not sure how to perform the actual check required by the server.  The remote server is not using SSL, and is using the SEAM framework.

Any tips on how to do this? I don't need Java code, just ideas on how to start this development. I already know how to load the card and the certs, but not how to pass the authentication with this info.

Comment: An alternative to your idea: have you looked at just scripting your web browser (with Selenium or similar)?  I've found that to be a helpful short-cut in the past, especially when I need to parse a web page after I fetch it.

Comment: It´s a greate idea, but I would like to run it at the background, via java console! Thanks.

Comment: It may be that your question does not provide enough information about the authentication protocol to be answered. Furthermore it may be that there are not many specialists on this site regarding this specific issue... Nathaniels remark does seem to make sense though.

Comment: Hello, I think this is a situation without solution, I need to authenticate via the applet, but the applet authenticate with another method inside with soap, well, it´s a lost cause :( thanks.